# Iterating through a list vs folder in python

Tags: python

I have a folder with hundreds of gigs worth of files. I have a list of filenames that I need to find from the folder.

My question is, is it faster if I iterate through the files in the folder (using glob for example) or create a list of all the file names and then iterate through that?

My initial assumption would be that creating a list would naturally be faster than iterating through the folder every time but since the list would contain hundreds of items, I'm not a 100% sure which is more efficient.

Comment: have you tried one against the other?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1445/

Comment: I have not, the xkcd comic is indeed the reason why. I am on a deadline unfortunately or I'd take my time with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list containing hundreds of filenames shouldn't be a performance problem. But for functions like glob you can often find [an iterator form](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) that streams the data for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your list of desired filenames. Write a simple lambda:

```
lambda curr_item: curr_item in desired_list
```

And then use `filter` to go over the directory.

```
desired_list = list() # your list of the files you seek
found_filenames = filter(lambda el: el in desired_list, os.listdir(bigfolder)
```

But, what do you want to do with the files next? That kinda depends on what to do.